# How to check if a pair already exists?

Tags: java

I have a string say "abab" and im splitting it in pairs.(i.e ab,ab) If pair already exists then i dont want it to be generated.How do i do it
Here's the code for what ive tried

```
      String r="abab";
      String  pair[] = new String[r.length()/2];
      for( int i = 0; i <pair.length; i++ ) 
      {
          pair[i] = r.substring(i*2,(i*2)+2);
      }
```

Comment: Are pairs you want to detect always at even indices? What about if there is "abcab"?

Comment: Why not `for(int i = 0; i < pair.length; i += 2)`?

Comment: @ fge if there are even number of letters ,padding must be done,which I dont know how to do

Comment: @ Matthew it prints only the first pair

Answer (score 1):

Before adding it to the pair array you could see if it already exists with the Arrays function .contains. If the pair already exists then don't add it to the pair list. For example here the ab and fe pairs will not be added:

```
  String r="ababtefedefe";
  String  pair[] = new String[r.length()/2];
  String currentPair = "";
  for( int i = 0; i <pair.length; i++ ) 
  {
      currentPair = r.substring(i*2,(i*2)+2);
      if(!java.util.Arrays.asList(pair).contains(currentPair))
        pair[i] = currentPair;
      System.out.println(pair[i]);
  }
```

Comment: @ yair doesnt work properly, my input was like "abababfefe" and it printed "ababfe", whereas i want only ab and fe to be printed

Comment: If you want it to print only those try doing a system.out.print  when the pair is not already in the pair array, so inside the if statement, after pair[i]=currentPair put System.out.print(pair[i]);

Comment: Still doesnt work, what i want is that if a pair is already existing then dont generate the pair again,thats my requirement.

Comment: What is your input and what is your output? I assumed from you question that the input is the string with the pairs and the output I am not sure about. Should the output be a string with pairs removed?  In other words if your input is "abababfefe" your output should be "abfe"?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i want,im taking a string abab,splitting into pairs (i.e ab ab) , then remove repetition of pairs.so output is just "ab".

Comment: In that case just initialize another string variable at the top and set in the if statement after pair[i] = currentPair like so newStr += pair[i];  This newStr string will have that output.

Comment: Thanks,it worked! However I tried printing random positions for each pair,and it worked for pairs like "abcd", prints random position for ab and cd seperately,but fr an input like "ababfefe" it prints "ab fe" and prints random position only for first pair and says null pinter excpetion,Can you help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Set to help me out.

```
private String[] retrieveUniquePair(String input) {
    int dim = input.length() / 2;
    Set<String> pairs = new LinkedHashSet<>(dim);

    for (int i = 0; i <= dim; i += 2) {
        String currentPair = input.substring(i, i + 2);
        pairs.add(currentPair);
    }

    return pairs.toArray(new String[] {});
}
```

**Edit:**
I post the solution I propose and the test

```
public class PairTest {

    @DataProvider(name = "input")
    public static Object[][] input() {
        return new Object[][] {
                {"abcd", Arrays.asList("ab", "cd")},
                {"abcde", Arrays.asList("ab", "cd")},
                {"abcdab", Arrays.asList("ab", "cd")},
                {"ababcdcd", Arrays.asList("ab", "cd")},
                {"ababtefedefe", Arrays.asList("ab", "te", "fe", "de")},
        };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "input")
    public void test(String input, List<String> expectedOutput) {
        String[] output = retrieveUniquePair(input);

        Assert.assertNotNull(output);
        Assert.assertEquals(output.length, expectedOutput.size());
        for (String pair : output) {
            Assert.assertTrue(expectedOutput.contains(pair));
        }
    }

    private String[] retrieveUniquePair(String input) {
        int pairNumber = input.length() / 2;
        Set<String> pairs = new LinkedHashSet<>(pairNumber);

        int endIteration = input.length();
        if (input.length() % 2 != 0) { // odd number
            endIteration--; // ignore last character
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < endIteration; i += 2) {
            String currentPair = input.substring(i, i + 2);
            pairs.add(currentPair);
        }

        return pairs.toArray(new String[pairs.size() - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use `return pairs.toArray(new String[0]);` - but your loop doesn't look right, it will only go to the middle position + 2.